# toolbar not showing in ckeditor5 decoupled-document using angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor5, angular10

Trying to use `CKeditor5 decoupled document` in `Angular-10` and having problem in getting toolbar

**Component.ts**

```
import * as CKeditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';

export class MyComponent {
    editor = CKeditor
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<ckeditor [editor]="editor" [config]="{ toolbar: [ 'bold' 'underline'] }"></ckeditor>
```

Here is the output image below as you can see there is no toolbar visible.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the only you need to do is inserting the `editor.ui.toolbar.element`, the DOM, in the HTML.

So what can we do here? When the component in Angular is Ready, append the toolbar.ui DOMElement in the editor element.

The following code comes from the CKEditor5 Document.

```
public onReady( editor ) {
    editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
        editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
        editor.ui.getEditableElement()
    );
}
```

Ref: [Documnt](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#using-the-document-editor-build)